Failed to allocate TLS context
On trying to enable https from working http setup for the FOTA/DFU using steps provided in the following link: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-job-over-https-for-nordic-semiconductor-nrf9160-dk
I came across the following issue/error:

my tools and setup:
IDE : VS Code
Programmer : Stm32Cube programmer
Debugger: St-link
OS: Zephyr 3.6
MCU: Stm32u5 series
Bootloader: mcuboot
Any ideas why this error is reported after enabling the https protocol instead of http for the download client of firmware image update?
Error: net_sock_tls: Failed to allocate TLS context
Just to clarify that the FOTA ( Firmware update over the air) works ok with nrf fota libraries and aws job/fota libraries on stm32 device while image download is enabled via http protocol.

In the prj.conf file This config was set to 1
CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_TLS_MAX_CONTEXTS=1
After increasing it to 3 fixed the issue.
CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_TLS_MAX_CONTEXTS=3
